# Go back to a point in time in git

Tags: git

In Perforce or TFS,  there was the ability to go back to a point in time in the repo.  For example get version, by time,  Oct 27 12:54:07.

It doesn't look like we have this ability in git.  Is this correct?
Do we then need to make a checkpoint or something each time we do a release build?

Comment: I guess that you are looking for tags ?

Comment: It's pretty common to make a tag whenever you do a release build.  This eliminates some ambiguity that might occur if doing it based just on dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to return to the precise version of the repository at the time you do a build it is best to tag the commit from which you make the build.

There are techniques to return the repository to the most recent commit in a branch as of a certain time-- but they might not always suffice.  For example, if you build from a branch, and later delete the branch, or build from a branch that is later rebased, the commit you built from can become "unreachable" in git from any current branch.  Unreachable objects in git may eventually be removed when the repository is compacted.

Putting a tag on the commit means it never becomes unreachable, no matter what you do with branches afterwards (barring removing the tag).